# Angular delay route change until all animations have finished

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to delay a route update until after animations have finished running. I am looping through the elements and adding a class which has a CSS animation associated with it. I can't get it to wait for all the animations to finish, it only seems to wait for the first one.

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'home',
        resolve: {
            delay: function($q, $animate){

                var promises = [];

                $('.animate').each(function(e){
                    var promise = $animate.addClass(this, 'animate-out');
                    promises.push(promise);
                });

                return $q.all(promises);
            }
        },
        showNav: false
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added ngAnimate dependency to your module?

Comment: Yes, it current looks like this:
 angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])

Comment: The promise is never being resolved.  Call the .then() method to resolve the promise.

Comment: I tried adding it to the end of $animate.addClass(this, 'animate-out').then() and also $q.all(promises).then(); but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I did a quick test and it seemed to work using $timeout instead, it waits and resolves all the promises together, but using $animate it just waits for the first promise then resolves the others straight away after despite the animations not finishing...

Answer (score 0):

If I use $animate.addClass for all the elements but only return a single promise for the final element it still has the same issue, like its overwriting $animate or something...

I have found a work around for the issue by adding up the duration and the delay times for the elements and then only using $animate.addClass for the one with the longest duration.

```
delay: function($animate){
    var $element = null,
        duration = 0;

    $('.animate').each(function(){
        var currentDuration = parseFloat($(this).css('animation-duration')) + parseFloat($(this).css('animation-delay'));
        if(currentDuration >= duration){
            duration = currentDuration;
            $element = this;
        }
    }).not($element).addClass('animate-out');

    return $element ? $animate.addClass($element, 'animate-out') : true;
}
```

I am sure there must be a better way to do this though?